# Чем заменить deprecated new Date().toLocaleString();

Tags: java, android, format, локаль

Как заменить deprecated

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
```

в Андроиде;
Дайте пример...

Answer (score 5):

> Документация андроида - Г. Я по этой ссылке уже 3 раза сегодня заходил, но так и не нашел ответ, как вывести рускую дату

[@Andreyua](/users/18910/andreyua), научитесь уже пользоваться документацией, а не ругать её. Идём и смотрим метод [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#toLocaleString()), где написано следующее:

> **This method was deprecated in API level 1.**
>
> Use **[DateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)** instead.

Далее, идём по ссылке, заботливо предоставленной нам документацией, и видим в самом начале страницы пример кода, сполна отвечающий на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Выбросило 03-01 23:07:13.970  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 01 янв. 1970 г.
03-01 23:07:13.970  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 01 янв. 1970 г.
03-01 23:07:13.970  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 01 янв. 1970 г. 3:00:00
03-01 23:07:13.980  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 01 янв. 1970 г. 0:00:00
03-01 23:07:13.980  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 3:00:00
03-01 23:07:13.980  19148-19148/? I/System.out﹕ 0:00:00

А как сделать, чтобы было "января" а не янв. :)

Comment: @Andreyua, всё же настоятельно советую вам хотя бы поверхностно ознакомиться с документацией, например, по предложенным мною и @metalurgus ссылкам. Там содержатся ответы на все эти вопросы.

Comment: Ладно, хотел на "блюдечке", так как другим занят, но, видимо, не получится. :) Видимо, только на stackoverflow.com так можно, а тут нет - русские такие суровые парни. )

Answer (score 3):

Есть такая штука, как DateFormat. Пользуюсь таким ее вариантем, как SimpleDateFormat.  
Работает примерно так:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");
format.format(new Date()); // 2015-03-01 22:47:34.481 EET
```

За обозначениями всех этих букаф идем в [документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Ну а чтобы "русскую" дату выкинуло. Я же поэтому и указал - toLocaleString . Документация андроида - Г. Я по этой ссылке уже 3 раза сегодня заходил, но так и не нашел ответ, как вывести рускую дату

Comment: @Andreyua Документация отличная. Это вы читать не умеете.

Comment: Не фига не отличная, у вас понимание "отличного" видимо отсутсвует

Comment: @Andreyua с таким отношением далеко пойдёшь...

Comment: Спасибо ) Несомненно )

Comment: @Andreyua, это у вас отсутствует понимание отличной документации. Поверьте, это не случай, когда написаны примеры на все случаи жизни. Мне хватило полторы минуты, что бы разобраться, как работает SimpleDateFormat. Вы же потратили намного больше времени на то,что бы упросить здешних ребят сделать это за вас. Это называется лень. Тут такое не приветствуется. Да и вообще мало где приветствуется...